# How to create a Message (Email) Object and mark it as "Sent" without sending it with Microsoft Graph API? C# and/or Java Graph SDK

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am looking for a way to create an email object in Outlook using the Microsoft Graph Api and to mark the object as "Sent" so it does not show up in outlook as a draft.

I have done the following:

---

- Mark the item's property "isDraft" to be false,
- Upload the item directly into the sentMail Mailbox
- give the item a valid sentTime in the past
- Every combination of the above three.

---

No matter what i do, when i navigate to outlook mail, the email shows up as a draft in my mailbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Graph API mail office 365: Is any option create inbox message NOT as Draft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008005/microsoft-graph-api-mail-office-365-is-any-option-create-inbox-message-not-as-d)

Comment: Yes! that answered my question! Since i'm in c# i had to use the objects built into the Graph SDK, but the logic was the same as found in that link, set the specific id and the value of the extended property and it worked. thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is located at [Microsoft Graph API mail office 365: Is any option create inbox message NOT as Draft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008005/microsoft-graph-api-mail-office-365-is-any-option-create-inbox-message-not-as-d)

It should be noted that for those using the Graph SDK you must use the built in properties and objects to set the options listed in the above link. Its the first answer that has the value: "4" attached to it that worked for my specific problem.

Data type in question for C# graph SDK -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0