# how to differentiate Sent and Received messages in graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, ms-office, message

I'm working with mailbox messages using Graph API. How to classify the messages as sent or received?

I found the similar query,[Is there a way to differentiate an inbound (received) versus outbound (sent) email/message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017059/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-an-inbound-received-versus-outbound-sent-ema)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below queries and see if this helps your scenario:

1. To identify sent message - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=sender/emailAddress/address eq 'your mail address'
2. To identify received message - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=sender/emailAddress/address ne 'your email address'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when user sends mail to himself, the received inbox mail is identified as a sent mail. Also what if user sent a mail with delegation of other user (send as permission), sent mails in user mailbox is identified as received. Any idea to overcome this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps and see if this helps your scenario:

1. [Get the mail folder collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) directly under the root folder of the signed-in user. The returned collection includes any mail search folders directly under the root.

   ```
    GET /me/mailFolders
   ```
2. Get messages in a specific folder in the user's mailbox - Use [list messages endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for this.

   ```
    GET /me/mailFolders/{id}/messages
   ```